# How to implement Alphabets in the sidebar of android listview

Tags: android, listview, alphabetical

Can any one provide me simple advice on how to add Alphabets on the sidebar of Android listview.
Whenever user taps on it, it should directly go to the letters of the list.

If any one has sample example or demo code share it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://twistbyte.com/tutorial/android-listview-with-fast-scroll-and-section-index

Setting `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"` on the ListView gives you the scrolling grab bar. You then edit your arrayadapter by implementing `SectionIndexer` to show the letters next to the grab bar.